# Lexer in Haskell - How to Pattern Match specific case?

Tags: html, haskell, design-patterns, token, matching

I'm currently working on a lexer written in Haskell, and am almost finished, but am running into a problem for a special case token. Currently, my lexer takes an input string and breaks down the statement into tokens for numbers, variable names, and specific tokens such as "if", "else", and "then".

It works great for all of my tokens, except for one that is "000...".

I was taught to use the span function, so I have my lexer use the isDigit and isAlphaNum boolean functions to parse the input. However, because "000..." starts with a zero, it automatically returns as a number. Additionally, the period is a token in the grammar as well, so the result of inputting "000..." in my lexer currently results in "0" "." "." ".".

I'm not proficient in the language of Haskell, but is it possible to match a string using isPrint, and use cases to handle instances of strings and integers? I'm at a loss for words right now, and it seems everything I have tried broke my program. My current pattern matching part looks like this:

```
lexer (c:cs)
| isSpace c = lexer cs
| isDigit c = lexDigit (c:cs)
| isAlphaNum c = lexString (c:cs)
| True = InvalidToken c : lexer cs

lexString 
| s1 == "if" = IfToken : lexer s2 
| s1 == "else" = ElseToken : lexer s2 
| s1 == "then" = ThenToken : lexer s2 
| s1 == "000..." = Zero : lexer s2
| True = StringToken s1 : lexer s2 
where (s1,s2) = (span isAlphaNum cs)
```

Any help is appreicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the idiomatic way to approach such a task in Haskell is to use a *parser combinator library*, such as [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec). <sub>(It may make sense to go the traditional parser/lexer route for some applications, but this isn't really something you should code by hand – use a lexer *generator*, i.e. [alex](https://www.haskell.org/alex/).)</sub>

Now, if you determined to do this by hand, and without more expressive parser combinators... you'll need to handle that special case in `lexDigit`, rather than `lexString`:

```
lexDigit :: String -> [Token] -- Always use type signatures!
lexDigit cs
  | ("000...",s2) <- splitAt 6 cs  = Zero : lexer s2
lexDigit cs = ... -- your original definition of `lexDigit`

lexString :: String -> [Token]
lexString cs = case s1 of
  "if"   -> IfToken : lexer s2 
  "else" -> ElseToken : lexer s2 
  "then" -> ThenToken : lexer s2
  -- no clause for "000...", since it can't happen here anyway
  _      -> StringToken s1 : lexer s2 
 where (s1,s2) = (span isAlphaNum cs)

lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer cs@(c:cs')
  | isSpace c    = lexer cs'
  | isDigit c    = lexDigit cs
  | isAlphaNum c = lexString cs
  | otherwise    = InvalidToken c : lexer cs'
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a live saver! Yeah I'm not allowed to use any libraries for this, and my knowledge of Haskell can be summed up with the 5 minute tutorial on their site and a bit of readings on pattern matching. Cheers!